# How can I plot cumulative plots with specific x values?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, cdf

I was trying to find out, how to plot a cumulative distribution function (cdf) with specific x values but was not successful.

For example, if the dataset is:

```matlab
x = [2.50 5.21 7.67 8.43 9.15 11.47 14.59 21.45];
y = [0.20 0.09 0.15 0.13 0.17  0.04  0.7   0.15];  % (total 1)
```

the graph shape definitely looks wrong, when I use `y = cdfplot(x)`.

I also plotted the graph with `cumsum(y)` and `x` to check the shape and it looks fine, but I would like to know, if there is any code which plots cumulative distribution plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`stairs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) function for creating "stairstep graphs", which should be exactly what you want, incorporating your `cumsum(y)` idea.

Please see the following code snippet. I added two additional points for the start and end of some interval, here `[0 ... 25]`. Also, your values in `y` sum up to something larger than 1, so I modified these values, too.

```matlab
x = [0 2.50 5.21 7.67 8.43 9.15 11.47 14.59 21.45 25];
y = [0 0.10 0.09 0.05 0.10 0.14  0.04  0.4   0.08  0];
stairs(x, cumsum(y));
xlim([-1 26]);
ylim([-0.2 1.2]);
```

That'd be the output (Octave 5.1.0, but also tested with MATLAB Online):

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much HansHirse! Your answer definitely helped! Also appreciate editing my original questions. I hope you to have a great day!